# Группировка результатов тестирования с помощью EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, olap

В базе данных SQL Server есть таблица c результатами тестирования учеников:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таблице у некоторых учеников (по некоторым предметам) есть результаты по **двум годам** (2014 и 2015 гг.). Необходимо отобрать учеников, у которых результаты по **математике** есть по **двум годам**.

Здесь, как вы наверное уже поняли, я представил только "кусок" таблицы для удобства представления проблемы. В реальности же это таблица состоит из 10000 строк и множества предметов.

Чтобы отобрать результат ученика сначала за 2014 год затем за 2015 год (для сравнения динамики) я использую, как мне кажется, довольно сложный алгоритм:

```
    baseEntities dataContext = new baseEntities();
    var union2014 = from year2014 in dataContext.results
                    join year2015 in dataContext.results
                    on year2014.ID_ученика equals year2015.ID_ученика
                    where year2014.Год == 2014 && year2014.Предмет=="математика"
                    && year2015.Год == 2015 && year2015.Предмет == "математика"
                    select year2014;

    var union2015 = from year2014 in dataContext.results
                    join year2015 in dataContext.results
                    on year2014.ID_ученика equals year2015.ID_ученика
                    where year2014.Год == 2014 && year2014.Предмет == "математика"
                    && year2015.Год == 2015 && year2015.Предмет == "математика"
                    select year2015;

    foreach(var result in union2014)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.ID_ученика + ", " + result.Предмет + ", " + result.Год + ", " + result.Оценка);                
        var resultLearner2015 = union2015.Where(x=>x.ID_ученика == result.ID_ученика).Single();
        Console.WriteLine(resultLearner2015.ID_ученика + ", " + resultLearner2015.Предмет + ", " + resultLearner2015.Год + ", " + resultLearner2015.Оценка);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне упростить данный код? Уверен, что можно использовать *GroupBy* или *Union*.

Сейчас параллельно изучаю OLAP - насколько я выяснил, для подобных задач легче всего использовать многомерный анализ. А пока хотелось бы услышать советы по решению подобных задач с помощью реляционной модели.

Comment: Не совсем уверен в коде но мне кажется ка кто так `dataContext.results.Where(t=>t.Предмет == "математика").GroupBy(t=>new {t.ID_ученика,t.Предмет ,t.Год}).select(t=> new{ t.key.ID_ученика, t.key.Предмет,t.key.Год,t.Оценка.First()}).Tolist();`

Comment: Выполняя запросы к крупным таблицам в своем клиенте, вы гоняете по сети довольно крупный объем данных, логичнее было бы выполнять подобный запрос на сервере, а в клиенте работать с его результатом

Comment: посмотрите немного измененный [вариант](https://dotnetfiddle.net/D17Jbc)  ответа @PashaPash

Comment: @Mirdin я полностью согласен с тобой. Но как выполнять подобный запрос на `стороне сервера`? Может ты имеешь в виду необходимость создания `сервера приложений`?

Comment: @adamshakhabov, можно конечно создать и серверную часть, своего приложения, но я скорее имел ввиду хранимые процедуры, EF с ними отлично имеет работать. Нюанс будет тот, не увлекитесь, таким образом можно существенно запутать логику приложения. Ну или другие средства вашего сервера бд.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var mathResults = dataContext.Results
    // фильтр по предмету и годам
    .Where(r => r.Предмет == "математика" && (r.Год == 2014 || r.Год == 2015))
    .GroupBy(r => r.ID_Ученика) // сгруппированные по ученику
    .Where(g => g.Count() >= 2) // группы с двумя результатами
    .SelectMany(r => r) // в плоский список
    .ToList();
```

если нужен только список таких учеников, без самих результатов, то вместо `SelectMany(r => r)`:

```
    .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from r in dataContext.results
    where r.Предмет == "математика" && new List<int> {2014, 2015}.Contains(r.Год)
    group r by r.id
    into grp
    where grp.Count() > 1
    select grp;
```